Why msg.value is not transferred to the owner?
I've deployed a simple wallet contract. 
The withdraw function goes like this.. 
function withdraw() external payable {
    require(msg.sender == owner, "Only Owner can withdraw");
    payable(msg.sender).transfer(msg.value);
}

In this case, the msg.value is not transferred to the owner. 
But when I pass the value as a parameter to the function, it is transferred. 
Tried something like this 
function withdraw(uint256 _amount) external payable {
    require(msg.sender == owner, "Only Owner can withdraw");
    payable(msg.sender).transfer(_amount);
}

The same goes with when I try to transfer with Call method. 
Could someone explain it? 
Thanks

This code doesn't make sense. You're trying to withdraw the amount you're sending to the contract at the time of calling the function withdraw. In other words, your money will just make a round trip, from the owner to the contract and back to the owner. Therefore, the balance of the contract doesn't change.
I assume you are trying to withdraw the entire balance of the contract. If that's the case, you need this:
payable(msg.sender).transfer(address(this).balance);

